# Reset modelsim editor to the default one

Tags: editor, modelsim

I want to reset my editor to the default one in `Modelsim` but I don't know how.

When I double click on a project it opens in `Notepad`. I tried to change the value of the `editor` variable from the "`Edit Preferences`" tab but it didn't work.

I also tried to change the windows settings to open it with `Modelsim.exe` and it worked for the first project only, but when I want to open another project it enters a loop where it keeps opening Modelsim again and again. What is the right way to do so?

Comment: I never tried change editor in my life cuz I mostly use command line and use vim as main editor. Can you leave the value as "blank/nothing"?

Comment: For the project specific, normally when you create project, it already copy an new modelsim.ini to its folder. Try to change it as reference to system 'smodelsim.ini (actually not recommend). Or you can change the system modelsim.ini and later project will be applied.

Comment: @KhanhN.Dang Yes I did, I also read that setting it to '1' should solve the problem but it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i could bypass this problem by typing "edit filename.vhd" without the double quotes in the transcript (that window that looks like console at the bottom of modelsim). however this is not a radical solution.

Comment: yes this method works but then you should uncheck in the editor the "Read Only" option.

Answer (score 4):

Follow below steps :

- Go to properties
- Click on change in open with
- Click on look for another app
- Go to the directory of model sim
- Select modelsim_ase
- Select win32aloem
- Select Vish
- Click open
- Click apply

Everything would be normal

Answer (score 2):

Although the issue seems to be with ModelSim, it really is an issue with Windows. As you noted, you have associated a file type (in this case, .vhd) with a given program, and now you need to undo it in order to get ModelSim to work as it did initially.

The following is the manual method for removing file associations for the .vhd extension in Windows 10:

1. (Search for and) run *regedit* command.
2. In the left sidebar of the *regedit* GUI, navigate to \Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
3. Delete the ".vhd" directory.
4. Navigate to \Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.
5. Delete the ".vhd" directory.
6. Navigate to \Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Roaming\OpenWith\FileExts.
7. Delete the ".vhd" directory.
8. You may or may not need to restart ModelSim and/or your computer.

---

UPDATE

Performing just steps 6 and 7 may fix the issue by itself, so try those first, then proceed with steps 4 and 5, check again if that fixes the issue, and so on.

You will need to repeat the fix every time that you perform `Open With` on a .vhd file, even if you `Open With` and then cancel (i.e. do not select an application and do not open said file).

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-click your .v file of interest in file explorer
2. Open with...
3. Select ModelSim
4. Select Always Open With
5. Let the file open up, then close the window

You should be back to normal now when double-clicking the files in ModelSim.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to one of your .v files , right click on it , select properties , then click "Change" which lies in front of the "Opens with" option , then select "choose another application from this PC , and navigate to the .exe file of the editor application you would like to use , select it and press apply then OK.
Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of opening with modelsim.exe, open with vsim.exe. This will stop the never ending loop of opening Model Sim.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the command from menu 'Help->Register File Type', and restart the Modelsim. It will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your windows temporary files as following:

1. Exit all programs.
2. Press <kbd>WINDOWS</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the keyboard to bring up the Run window.
3. Type `%TMP%` and then click OK.
4. Delete the contents of the folder that opens up.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got solution to your problem:

1. Try to browse the verilog file thru the windows navigation panel.
2. Right Click the .v file.
3. SELECT "Open With".
4. BROWSE to the directory path or folder where the modelsim.exe is residing.
5. Select modelsim.exe.
6. After that, you should be able now to open the verilog file on ModelSim's own source code editor. ENJOY!!!

Answer (score 0):

Go on one of the files (for example .v file)
Open with-> Chose another app
Then find this C:\altera\13.0sp1\modelsim_ase\win32aloem\modelsim.exe
**On your pc it may be on an other location.** Chose that .exe
Close the program and try again.